# In visual Studio Code, How to list the functions on a side like in Notepad++?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I really like the feature of Notepad++ where you can click the function icon when editing a powershell document and it shows the list of every function on the right side panel. I really miss this feature when using visual studio code. Is there a way to make the function list show up on the side rather than as a ellipse drop down menu that disappears after selection?

Here's what the function list side panel looks like in Notepad++:

https://www.theroyweb.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/funclist_listview.png

I want this same feature enabled for visual studio code. Especially the search box above the function list side bar that searches the side panel of functions for string patterns.

Is there a plug-in that will enable this capability with visual studio code?

Answer (score 17):

There is the Outline panel, which is a part of the Explorer pane. Does this provide the functionality you' re looking for?

You can also find it through

> View --> Command Palette --> "outline", then choose  **'Explorer: Focus on Outline View'**

.

Comment: thanks.  didn't noticed that before.